# Datetime format when adding time durations

Tags: python, datetime, time

```
time_1 = datetime.timedelta(hours = hours_1, minutes = minutes_1, seconds = seconds_1)
time_2 = datetime.timedelta(hours = hours_2, minutes = minutes_2, seconds = seconds_2)
```

when added it gives the answer in `days` and `hours` but I really just want the total number of hours.

Answer (score 0):

This should help.

```
import datetime

time_1 = datetime.timedelta(hours = 10, minutes = 2, seconds = 5)
time_2 = datetime.timedelta(hours = 30, minutes = 5, seconds = 7)

print(time_1 + time_2)
print(((time_1 + time_2).total_seconds()/60)/60)
```

**Output:**

```
1 day, 16:07:12
40.12
```